# Sqoop importing zero decimals as 0E-22

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

When I import a table using hadoop and sqoop from my MSSQL database and that table has decimal columns any columns that are zero (eg 0.000000000000..) are saved as "0E-22".

This is quite a pain as when casting the value to a decimal in my Map or Reduce it throws an exception. So I either have to export the column as a varchar or to a check before trying to cast it. Neither are ideal.

Has anyone encountered this before and got a work around?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest trying soon to be released Sqoop [1.4.3](http://www.apache.org/dist/sqoop/1.4.3/), where we fixed [SQOOP-830](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-830)
 that might help you as well.

Comment: Thanks, I will be sure to keep my eyes open for when 1.4.3 is released!

Answer (score 0):

It is a strange case, there is some workaround. You can rewrite your_table, i.e.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE your_table
SELECT columns_no_need_for_change , CASE WHEN possible_bad_column = '0E-22' THEN '0' ELSE possible_bad_column END FROM your_table
```

Let us know how if you succeed or not. GL!